# Как одновременно запустить много python файлов/

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть 10 файлов и их нужно запустить одновременно(файлов потом будет еще больше),как это сделать?

В ручную через терминал долго и не удобно запускать, особенно если кол-во дойдет до 50.

P.s Каждый файл должен быть открыт отдельно, в новом окне(терминала), ибо со всеми ими надо отдельно взаимодействовать

Comment: напишите `bash` скрипт

Comment: по типу такого? xfce4-terminal -e sh -c "python3 1.py; bash" Я так сделал, но они поочереди запускаются, после закрытия одного.

Comment: пример по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377109/shell-script-execute-a-python-program-from-within-a-shell-script)

Comment: Каждый файл должен быть открыт отдельно, в новом окне(терминала), ибо со всеми ими надо отдельно взаимодействовать.

Answer (score 2):

`*.py` - glob разворачивает в список, проходим по этому списку и запускаем терминалы

```
for f in *.py; do
  gnome-terminal -- python3 $f &
done
```

& - отправляет задачу в фон. Для gnome-terminal не нужно потому как он клиент-серверный, для других терминалов может быть необходимо.